# How do I easily obfuscate an Android app when using IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, obfuscation, proguard

I imagine there are two options:

1. Build a parallel ANT script and bypass the IDE (seems pretty inefficient when the IDE is so good)
2. Somehow integrate Proguard/yGuard or similar with IntelliJ

I've tried installing plugins for Proguard/yGuard into IntelliJ but neither seem to be working (installed ok, but don't appear under Facets), and actually I'm not 100% sure these plugins will help me obfuscate or whether they just provide a de-obfuscation facility for debugging.

I figure ANT is the best route, but would appreciate your thoughts. I just want a way to reduce the chances of someone reverse-engineering apps, but without spending hours setting it up.

Comment: Just a note for others reading this question, I saw mention today of the upcoming new version of ADT for Eclipse that will apparently include direct support for Proguard, so obfuscation is built into the standard Eclipse Android development environment. That's great, and hopefully JetBrains will do likewise with IntelliJ

Comment: Building a whole application often is more difficult than just obfuscate/shrink using ProGuard. With ANT you ALWAYS are more flexible than with ANY IDE integration.

Comment: I started looking into this as well. If you came up with a better solution than an alternative Ant, would you mind sharing it?

Comment: I've not found a better solution yet. Obfuscation is essential for Android apps, I hope JetBrains realise this and at least provide a procedure people can follow. I expect it will take a few hours for me to get an ANT script set up and obfuscating the app, and those hours would be much better spent improving the app itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd vote for 1st option - write an ANT script. This has the advantage of being independent of the IDE, even a build server can run it easily.

Comment: I agree, Ant would be the best option, IDEA can run Ant both manually and automatically for the Run configuration

Comment: Surely the best option would be for the IDE to support it without me having to do much at all :-)

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is just open the project in Eclipse by creating a new project from existing sources. The two IDEs play quite nicely with each other.  Many teams use both and go back and forth between them.